# applet is not binded corectly to model

Tags: java, data-binding, nullpointerexception, applet, zk

i have big(for me) problem with zk application. I want to bind model to view but it doesn't work. When, i try do access applet in model, i get  error  java.lang.NullPointer

```
//index.zul
<?page title="Auto Generated index.zul"?>
<window id="mainWindow" title="edycja dokumentow" border="normal" 
apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('controller.EditDocsController')">
  <vbox>
    <listbox id="modelList" height="160px" model="@bind(vm.modelList)">
        <listhead>
            <listheader label="id" />
            <listheader label="open" />
        </listhead>
        <template name="model">
            <listitem>
                <listcell label="@bind(each)" />
                <listcell >
                    <button label="otworz"  onClick="@command('open',id=each)"/>                
                </listcell>
            </listitem>
        </template>         
    </listbox>      
     <applet  code="applet.EditFileApplet" codebase="applet" archive="EditApplet.jar" width="100px" height="100px" model="@save(vm.editApplet) before='open'"/>
     <!--<applet  code="applet.EditFileApplet" codebase="applet" archive="EditApplet.jar" width="100px" height="100px" model="@bind(vm.editApplet)'"/>  
          // I have tried these two version separetly   
  </vbox>
</window>
```

EditDocsController.java

```
public class EditDocsController {
  private DocsDAO docksDAO = new DocsDAO();

  private List<Integer> modelList;
  private Applet editApplet;

  public Applet getEditApplet()                         {       return editApplet;  }
  public void setEditApplet(Applet editApplet)      {       this.editApplet = editApplet;   }   
  public List<Integer> getModelList()                   {       return modelList;   }
  public void setModelList(List<Integer> modelList)     {       this.modelList = modelList; }


  @AfterCompose
  public void loadDock(){
    modelList = docksDAO.getData();
  /*    editApplet = new Applet();
    editApplet.setCode("applet.EditFileApplet");
    editApplet.setCodebase("applet");
    editApplet.setArchive("EditApplet.jar");*/
  }

  @Command
  public void open(@BindingParam("id") Integer id){
    editApplet.getArchive();
    editApplet.invoke("open", new String[]{id.toString(),"user jakiś tam"} );   
  }
}
```

thanks in advance, 
if You have any idea how repair it, please share it with me

---

here is all stack trace https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YZs7xgzxbOGo70sPogUdNn5IbwWGcq2YU1GRszEtdNk/edit?usp=sharing

here is the part of it, for me it is the most valuable

```
lut 28, 2014 1:19:56 PM org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall call
SEVERE: 
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.EditDocsController.open(EditDocsController.java:51) // the line editApplet.getArchive()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

lut 28, 2014 1:19:56 PM org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener onEvent
SEVERE: null
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.EditDocsController.open(EditDocsController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

lut 28, 2014 1:19:56 PM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError
SEVERE: 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.EditDocsController.open(EditDocsController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

lut 28, 2014 1:21:21 PM org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl addPropertySaveBindings0
 WARNING: component <Applet xLDQ7#myEditApplet> doesn't has event to save attribute  model at       [file:/C:/Users/bbur/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/RPO/index.zul, line:30]
```

I have made some changes in the code to cope with the problem but there is still a problem. i use this to init applet

```
  <applet id="myEditApplet" code="applet.EditFileApplet" codebase="applet" archive="EditApplet.jar" width="30px" height="30px" style="border: 1px"  />
```

change the button definition to

```
  <button label="otworz" onClick='myEditApplet.invoke("openDoc","1234")'/>
```

and i deleted the method open from EditDocsController

when I click the button "otworz", i get error "Failed to invoke applet's method: openDoc
undefined" despite the fact the method exist in applet class (public void openDoc(String idDoc)). The most annoying thing with it is that when i call 'myEditApplet.invoke("init")' everything is all right

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of exception.

Comment: Please do not post additional info as an answer. You can and should edit your question to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Applet` component in ZK has no `model` attribute, therefore you can't use it to save the applet reference in the viewmodel. (And in general `model` attribute is used not for that)

Instead you can assign an id to the applet and pass that id to the `open` command as a second parameter, something like this:

**index.zul**

```
...
    <button label="otworz"  onClick="@command('open', id=each, applet=editApplet)"/>
...
<applet id="editApplet" code="applet.EditFileApplet" codebase="applet"
        archive="EditApplet.jar" width="100px" height="100px"/>
...
```

**EditDocsController.java**

```
...
@Command
public void open(@BindingParam("id") Integer id, 
                 @BindingParam("applet") Applet applet){
    applet.invoke("open", new String[]{id.toString(),"user jakiś tam"} );   
}
```